# Create subtasks that override `options` but use task level `src`

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

My gruntfile thus far

```
uglify: {
    src: [
        ...
    ],
    dest: 'js/application.min.js',
    options: {
        'compress': {},
        'reserveDOMCache': true,
        'enclose': undefined,
        'exportAll': false,
        'expression': false,
        'preserveComments': false,
        'report': 'min',
        'sourceMap': false,
        'sourceMapIn': undefined,
        'sourceMapIncludeSources': false,
        'sourceMapName': undefined,
        'wrap': undefined
    },
    development: {
        options: {
            'beautify': false,
            'mangle': true
        }
    },
    production: {
        options: {
            'beautify': true,
            'mangle': false
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run the task `uglify:development` it will respond with `No files created.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. You need to explicitly define a src for each target.

You could declare a variable outside of the config and add it to each target:

```
var mySources = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']; //declared outside config

 development: {
     src: mySources, //add variable to each target
```

Or you can declare a variable inside the config:

```
mySourcesInside: ['file1.txt'], //declared within config

  development: {
       src: '<%= mySourcesInside%>', //reference variable in each target
```

Alternatively you could use something like `grunt-override-config` https://github.com/masakura/grunt-override-config and declare just one uglify target and overrides for the options.

Comment: I was able to adapt your solution to work the way I wanted to with `src: '<%= uglify.src%>'`